# Spring Security Access denied 403 after get

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

This url `http://localhost:8070/produits` with Postman works fine.It returns this :

[image]

After adding spring security, this url return 403 access denied even with correct username and password.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
    import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter    {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


        /*auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("1234").roles("ADMIN","USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("1234").roles("USER");*/

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery("select username as principal,password as credentials,active from users where username =?").
        authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username as principal,roles as role from users_roles where username =?")
        .rolePrefix("ROLE_").passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/produits").hasRole("USER");


    }


}
```

**The restful service**

```
@Autowired
private ProduitRepository produitRepository;


@RequestMapping(value="/produits",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Produit> listProduits()
{
    return produitRepository.findAll();
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried the `inMemoryAuthentication`? Just to be sure if you have a problem with the configuration of your `auth`.

Comment: Or its better to debug "JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(String username)" to find if the system is able to find given user successfully

Comment: @Afridi i stored the password encoded using MD5

Comment: Try without RolePrefix

Comment: Could you add Spring Security log with `DEBUG` enabled (in your log configuration)? It will show the reason for your problem. It could be CSRF (you didn't disable it) or it could be a problem with the name of your roles. Did you prefix your roles in your database?

Comment: i tried with static username and password but i has the same problem

auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("1234").roles("USER");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from your screenshot - you're trying to use basic auth in postman. If so, you should at least enable it. Try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/produits").hasRole("USER");
}
```

Comment: i tried your purpose but i has this problem:

Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

Comment: @AmirChoubani, you're getting this when you hit your `/product` URL? Can you please provide full URL, headers and so on?

Comment: the error no longer exist.
now , with http.httoBasic()  and with the url :

http://localhost:8070/produits

it shows the response without verifying username and password

Comment: @AmirChoubani, how do you know that username and password has not been verified?

Comment: even username and password are empty, it shows directly the response

Comment: @AmirChoubani, have you pressed "Update request" button in Postman, after changing values?